# VBA Invalid or Unqualified Reference Compile

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying to record a simple macro with the record Macro button. I just want to cut a Column and paste it two Columns after. I have tried this in other computers and it does work. It generates this code in VBA:

```
    Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
    '
        Columns("C:C").ErrorString
        .RequireManualUpdate
        Columns("E:E").ErrorString
        .
    End Sub
```

It gives me an error:

"Compile Error:

Invalid or unqualified reference."

Comment: If this is the **exact** result of your recording, there is something fundamentally wrong with either your computer or your Excel. That output of the macro recorder is far from being normal. If this happens to your computer only: Reboot, try again. If it doesn't help make sure you use the latest Office version or you can try to re-install Office.

Comment: [Related](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Excel-Macro-Recording-Generate-Wrong-VBA/td-p/190857)

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that you probably need an Office re-install, you'll want your macro to look something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
With Selection
    If .Columns.Count > 1 Or .Areas.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Select a single column."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    .EntireColumn.Cut
    .Offset(0, 3).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `If .Columns.Count > 1 Or .Areas.Count > 1 Then` other wise if you select column A and column C at the same time it will consider it as single column and throw an error on `.Cut`.

Comment: Yes, forgot that check. Code changed. Thanks @Pᴇʜ